# Foursquare / How to delete venues

Tags: foursquare

I've got a question about foursqure API:
I want to add a lot of venues. For this action I should use this method: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/add
If one of my venues will change I can use a method: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/edit

But what should I do if my venue will be closed? How can I delete a venue?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove a venue you should use the `venues/flag` endpoint here: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/flag

You provide a `problem` parameter, one of: `mislocated`, `closed`, `duplicate`, `inappropriate`, `doesnt_exist`, `event_over`

In your case, if a venue is closed you should pass `problem=closed`

Comment: Thank you very much